# Error in building a URL string in java

Tags: java, android, string

I am having a hard time in building a URL string which I want to use for HttpURLConnection.

Here is the string that I want to pass

```
http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=USD,GBP
```

The above string shall have all the parameter as dynamic, two Strings that I am using are **part1** and other **default_actv2**

I tried building string in following way

```
http://api.fixer.io/latest?base="+part1+"&symbols="+part1+","+default_actv2
```

and passing it into jsonTask in following way

```
new JSONTask().execute("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base="+part1+"&symbols="+part1+","+default_actv2);
```

When I print the value my code takes it as

```
http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=AED &symbols=AED ,INR
```

Notice the extra spaces after AED, as a result of such a string. I am getting error from the server side.

Could anybody help in explaining me the correct way of building a string with some code. I know there are tons of threads that answers this question, but somehow I am not able to get this thing working.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Call `trim()` on `part1`, apparently.

Comment: @CommonsWare: woah! thanks that solved my problem. I didn't noticed that. Love you for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .trim() on your **part1** string in order to deal with the extra space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache URIBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html).

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme("http")
        .setHost("api.fixer.io")
        .setPath("/latest")
        .addParameter("base", part1)
        .addParameter("symbol", part1 + "," + default_actv2)
        .build();
uri.toString();
```